# CSS: 4 items rendered in 2 columns when using column-count: 3

Tags: css, layout, masonry

I wanted to create a masonry layout of 3 columns to render items with same width but different height but then when I tried the code bellow I saw the third column is empty which seems a bit weird. can I fix it somehow?

I tried this code and I expect two items in first column, and one item in the second and third column. note that 4 items with same height is just a specific case, in the end I don’t how many items there will be and what height each item will have.

```css
.container {
  column-count: 3;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  width: 588px
}

.item {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  break-inside: avoid;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are pretty much at the mercy of the browser as to how it wants to distribute the items. For this case, you could apply `break-before: column` to the forth box to have it be in the third column, but this is not a general solution when you don't know how many items there are or their heights.

Comment: I am not seeing the third column empty when running your snippet. Could you check that the snippet is definitely showing the problem for you and say what OS and browser you are using?

Comment: the snippet is showing the problem for me, first column has 1 and 2, second column has 3 and 4, third is empty. I'm using macOS Monterey and chrome

Comment: Yes, I see it on Edge/Chome on Windows10 - before was on Safari/IOS.

Answer (score -2):

For that case, you can use a `display: flex` with `flex-wrap: wrap` and `justify-content: space-between` on the container

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  width: 588px
}

.item {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  break-inside: avoid;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a good solution for a masonry layout but thanks anyway

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).